# Ahoy gem, how to not save ahoy.track record into DB when page is reloaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ahoy

I want to count how many views my page has received.
So, I try to use the Ahoy gem and add the following line into my action:

https://github.com/ankane/ahoy#ruby

Then it records when a visitor views that `action`, but it also records every time the `action` has been called, even when user reloads the page.

What I want is: if this is that the user's first visit we record it. But if they just reload page or they re-visit that page in a short amount of time, we will not save `ahoy.track` into our DB.

So, do anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in your view :

```
<% ahoy.track_visit unless current_visit %>
```

Comment: when you have more reputation you can write comments. Never write comments as answers.

Comment: thanks for your comment , but it is an answer I guess